# Can't see host server on network

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I've got a server running windows server 2008 with hyper v is hosting 4 virtual machines.  Can see all of the VM's fine on the network, but can't see the host server and i need to access a shared folder on the host from the newest VM (running Windows Server 2008 R2).

Can ping host from everything but the new VM and the new VM can ping everything except the host. Can't '\192.168.x.x' host from the new VM and have turned both firewall off but no joy.

The host's network consists of the VM's it's hosting and nothing else.  I've tried turning the host's Network Discovery on but it will only set to 'Custom'

Any ideas why the host isn't showing and how i can get it to appear?

Many thanks.

Comment: Got the VM & host to talk to each other by adding a new internal network adapter in the virtual network manager of Hyper-V. Still can't get the host to appear on the network though...

Answer (score 1):

Open the virtual network manager, choose the network connection and click "allow management OS to share this network adapter."

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to have a better understanding of the different types of Hyper-V networking.  John Howard has an [excellent article](http://blogs.technet.com/jhoward/archive/2008/06/17/hyper-v-what-are-the-uses-for-different-types-of-virtual-networks.aspx) that spells out most everything you need to know about the various networking options.

Also, I [posted an article](http://www.dscoduc.com/2009/09/hyper-v-routing-without-a-router-vm/) that talks about enabling routing without having to build a VM Router...

Lastly, remember that Windows 2008 has an embedded firewall that is pretty restrictive by default.  You may need to modify the firewall rules to allow your VM's to talk to the Hyper-V Host.